# Previous, Next links in jQuery datatable appear too close

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatables and it's working as expected. The only issue is that the previous, next, page numbers links at the bottom are not very user friendly and they appear too close to each other.

How can I style them better.  This is what I want to achieve [image: target] .

And this is where I am currently [image: Current]

Jsp code

```
<div class="card-content collapse show">
    <div class="card-body card-dashboard">
        <table
            class="table table-striped table-bordered zero-configuration dataTable"
            id="userListDataTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>FirstName</th>
                    <th>LastName</th>
                    <th>Mobile No</th>
                    <th>View</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:set var="id" value="${1}" />
                <c:forEach var="user" items="${list}">
                    <tr>
                        <td><c:out value="${id}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${user.firstname}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${user.lastname}" /></td>
                        <td><c:out value="${user.mobile}" /></td>
                        <td><a
                            href="<c:url value = "/user/view/${user.id}"/>"> <i
                                class="fa fa-fw fa-eye"></i></a></td>
                        <td><a
                            href="<c:url value = "/user/edit/${user.id}"/>"> <i
                                class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
                        <td><a
                            href="<c:url value = "/user/delete/${user.id}"/>"><i
                                class="fa fa-fw fa-trash"></i></a></td>

                    </tr>
                    <c:set var="id" value="${id + 1}" />
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/43306/change-default-color-of-pagination-buttons

Answer (score 0):

This worked finally to introduce some gap between index ,next,previous buttons.

```
<style>
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
 padding: 5px
}

</style>
```